# How to use 2 models within a serializer in Django REST API?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I just started using the Django Rest Framework recently and was wondering how to use 2 models within a single serializer. I have a custom model named 'Profile' and am also using a default Django model 'User'. With these two tables, I planned to use **nested representations**. Finally, in order to test the RegisterAPI, I wanted to create data using the POSTMAN tool but currently, it's not working as expected.

This is what I had done so far:

**models.py:**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.TextField()
```

**views.py:**

```
class RegisterAPI(APIView):

    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            content = {
            'result': 'Thanks for registering!'
            }
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from myapp.models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['company', 'address']

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer(many = True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'profile']


    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)  
        # instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            user.set_password(password)
        user.save()  
        Profile.objects.create(user = user, **profile_data)
        return user
```

Within POSTMAN, I am not able to set the fields 'company' and 'address' for the Profile serializer. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried to set `ProfileSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)`?

Comment: I haven't since I wanted to create data in my Profile model. If I add the parameter 'read_only=True', wouldn't it stop me from creating data specific to the Profile model?